# C# - Messagebox asking for permission to continue

Tags: c#, visual-studio

can anyone suggest me a code for asking to click on yes or no to further persue or not in c#. I'm making a data base program and I want that a message box should sjow me the values to check and ask to click yes to continue or no to go back and modify

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(...)` ?

Comment: Have you Google your requirement first? You will find lots of references for this task on Google.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use MessageBox.Show. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx